# Vue and Stripe Checkout. vue-stripe throwing errors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, stripe-payments, vuejs2

I'm using Vue 2.0 and I'm trying to integrate the [vue-stripe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-stripe) module. This module integrates the [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) in a Vue component.

My application intends to let users buy the ticket for an event. I have an index.js file and some components.

I'm doing this `import { StripeCheckout } from 'vue-stripe'` in the index.js file. And then, in Event Page Component (where the user will be using the Checkout form), I do this:

```
components: {
        'stripe-checkout': StripeCheckout
}
```

However... this is throwing the following error:

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

What is happening? What am I doing wrong? How can I make this work?

This is the index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './components/App.vue'
import Home from './components/Home.vue'
import EventPage from './components/EventPage.vue'
import auth from './auth/index.js'
import VueAxios from 'axios'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import VueAuth from 'vue-auth'
import GSignInButton from 'vue-google-signin-button'
import vueSmoothScroll from 'vue-smooth-scroll'


Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(VueAuth)
Vue.use(GSignInButton)
Vue.use(vueSmoothScroll)

window.axios = VueAxios

export var router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    ...
  ]
})

const app = new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

And this is the EventPage.vue component:

...

```
import auth from '../auth'
import {router} from '../index'
import { Card, createToken } from 'vue-stripe-elements'
import { StripeCheckout } from 'vue-stripe'

export default {
...
}
```

I also tried importing the module in the index.js file

Comment: Could you show us your index.js file ?

Comment: It clearly says that `import` declaration is in the wrong place. Show your module.

Comment: I edited the question with the files. I tried importing the module in every place I thought it would work, but it really doesn't seem to be working anywhere.

Comment: I get this during the build: `export 'StripeCheckout' was not found in 'vue-stripe'`

Comment: Any updates from OP?